# Dynamic column sum total when adding a row with JS

Tags: javascript, datatable, row, calculated-columns, column-sum

Can someone help please? I have an editable table with column sum, using HTML and JS.

I tried to add a row, it's working but when I enter value on the new row, my total column is not changing dynamically, it's changing only after I use another row.

I just want to find how when I'm adding a new row and edit value content, it's changing the total of my column dynamically, not only when I used another row.

(Sorry I'm still training, if it's not perfect, I'm here to learn from my mistakes.)

Thanks,

Here is my code :

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Editable table -->
            <div class="card shadow-none border-top-0" style="border-color: #a8b698; background-color: #fff;">
                <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4" style="background-color: #fff; border-color: #fff;">Table de données</h3>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
                      <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
                        <a href="#!" class="text-success material-tooltip-main" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Ajouter une ligne"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      </span>
                      <table id="example" class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
                        <thead>
                            <!-- TITLES OF COLUMNS -->
                            <tr class="mescouilles">
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="false">Grade</th>
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">EFF THEO</th>
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">ABS</th>
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">PRESENT</th>
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">INDISPONIBLE</th>
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">SLR</th>
                            <th class="text-center" contenteditable="false">SUPPRIMER</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- OFF ROW -->
                            <tr class="cucul">
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="true">Off</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value2" type="number" name="value2" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value9" type="number" name="value9" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center colonneDeux" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value16" type="number" name="value16" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color: #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value23" type="number" name="value23" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value30" type="number" name="value30" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- S/OFF ROW -->
                            <tr>
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">S/OFF</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value3" type="number" name="value3" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value10" type="number" name="value10" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center colonneDeux" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value17" type="number" name="value17" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value24" type="number" name="value24" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value31" type="number" name="value31" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- CCH ROW -->
                            <tr>
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="flase">CCH</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value4" type="number" name="value4" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value11" type="number" name="value11" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value18" type="number" name="value18" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value25" type="number" name="value25" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value32" type="number" name="value32" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- CPL ROW -->
                            <tr>
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">CPL</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value5" type="number" name="value5" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value12" type="number" name="value12" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value19" type="number" name="value19" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value26" type="number" name="value26" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value33" type="number" name="value33" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- ICL ROW -->
                            <tr>
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">ICL</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value6" type="number" name="value6" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value13" type="number" name="value13" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value20" type="number" name="value20" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value27" type="number" name="value27" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value34" type="number" name="value34" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- LEG ROW -->
                            <tr>
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">LEG</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value7" type="number" name="value7" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value14" type="number" name="value14" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value21" type="number" name="value21" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value28" type="number" name="value28" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                                <input id="value35" type="number" name="value35" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #b0bda2;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 shadow-none">SUPPRIMER</button></span>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <!-- TOTAL OF COLUMNS -->
                            <tr style="background-color: #c5d3b6; border-width: 3px;">
                            <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false" >TOTAL</td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                                <input disabled="disabled" id="sum" type="number" name="sum" value="" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #c5d3b6;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                                <input disabled="disabled" id="sum2" type="number" name="sum2" value="" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #c5d3b6;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                                <input disabled="disabled" id="sum3" type="number" name="sum3" value="" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #c5d3b6;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                                <input disabled="disabled" id="sum4" type="number" name="sum4" value="" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #c5d3b6;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td contenteditable="false">
                                <input disabled="disabled" id="sum5" type="number" name="sum5" value="" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #c5d3b6;"/>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                      </table>
                  </div>
              </div>
           </div>
<!-- Editable table -->
</body>
```

```js
// Add new and Del a row
const $tableID = $('#table');
const $BTN = $('#export-btn');
const $EXPORT = $('#export');
const newTr = `
<tbody>
    <tr class="border-bottom-1">
        <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Nouvelle ligne"><i class="fas fa-plus text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input id="value1" type="number" name="value1" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input id="value8" type="number" name="value8" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input id="value15" type="number" name="value15" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input id="value22" type="number" name="value22" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input id="value29" type="number" name="value29" value="0" placeholder="0" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td><span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>`;

// Add/clone, new column (on click) without showing my first clonable row.
$('.table-add').on('click', 'i', () => {

const $clone = newTr;

if ($tableID.find('tbody tr').length === 0) {

    $('tbody').append(newTr);
}

$tableID.find('table').prepend($clone);
});

$tableID.on('click', '.table-remove', function () {

    $(this).parents('tr').detach();
});

$tableID.on('click', '.table-up', function () {

    const $row = $(this).parents('tr');

    if ($row.index() === 0) {
        return;
    }

    $row.prev().before($row.get(0));
});

$tableID.on('click', '.table-down', function () {

    const $row = $(this).parents('tr');
    $row.next().after($row.get(0));
});

// A few jQuery helpers for exporting only
jQuery.fn.pop = [].pop;
jQuery.fn.shift = [].shift;

$BTN.on('click', () => {

    const $rows = $tableID.find('tr:not(:hidden)');
    const headers = [];
    const data = [];

// Get the headers (add special header logic here)
$($rows.shift()).find('th:not(:empty)').each(function () {

    headers.push($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

// Turn all existing rows into a loopable array
$rows.each(function () {
    const $td = $(this).find('td');
    const h = {};

    // Use the headers from earlier to name our hash keys
    headers.forEach((header, i) => {

        h[header] = $td.eq(i).text();
    });

    data.push(h);
});

// Output the result
$EXPORT.text(JSON.stringify(data));
});



// Sum of each column
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#value1, #value2, #value3, #value4, #value5, #value6, #value7").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("#value1, #value2, #value3, #value4, #value5, #value6, #value7").each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum").val(total);
    });
    $("#value8, #value9, #value10, #value11, #value12, #value13, #value14").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("#value8, #value9, #value10, #value11, #value12, #value13, #value14").each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum2").val(total);
    });
    $("#value15, #value16, #value17, #value18, #value19, #value20, #value21").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("#value15, #value16, #value17, #value18, #value19, #value20, #value21").each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum3").val(total);
    });
    $("#value22, #value23, #value24, #value25, #value26, #value27, #value28").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("#value22, #value23, #value24, #value25, #value26, #value27, #value28").each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum4").val(total);
    });
    $("#value29, #value30, #value31, #value32, #value33, #value34, #value35").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $("#value29, #value30, #value31, #value32, #value33, #value34, #value35").each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $("#sum5").val(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point relying on ids when you are inserting an unlimited amount of elements.

In solution below I added `data-col` attribute on every `input` in the `tbody` so I could easily find a column it belongs to. After that I'm looping over every `input`, in the column that triggered the event, to calculate the total. In the end I'm updating the value of `input` in `tfoot` in the same column.

```js
const $tableID = $("#table");
const newTr = `
<tbody>
    <tr class="border-bottom-1">
        <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Nouvelle ligne"><i class="fas fa-plus text-success" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input  type="number" name="value1"  value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="1" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input  type="number" name="value8" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="2" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input type="number" name="value15" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="3" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input type="number" name="value22" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="4" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><input  type="number" name="value29" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="5" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color:  #fff;"/></td>
        <td><span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">SUPPRIMER</button></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>`;

// Add/clone, new column (on click) without showing my first clonable row.
$(".table-add").on("click", "i", () => {
  const $clone = newTr;

  if ($tableID.find("tbody tr").length === 0) {
    $("tbody").append(newTr);
  }

  $tableID.find("table").prepend($clone);
});

$tableID.on("click", ".table-remove", function() {
  $(this).parents("tr").detach();
});

// Sum of the column where the event was triggerred
$tableID.on("input", (event) => {
  // Getting index of the column
  const colNum = +event.target.dataset.col;
  let total = 0;

  // Looping over every row
  $("tbody tr").each((i, tr) => {
    total += +$(tr)
      .find("input")
      // Getting only the input in the same column as the triggered one
      .eq(colNum - 1)
      .val();
  });

  $("tfoot input")
    .eq(colNum - 1)
    .val(total);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Editable table -->
  <div class="card shadow-none border-top-0" style="border-color: #a8b698; background-color: #fff;">
    <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4" style="background-color: #fff; border-color: #fff;">
      Table de données
    </h3>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div id="table" class="table-editable">
        <span class="table-add float-right mb-3 mr-2">
          <a
            href="#!"
            class="text-success material-tooltip-main"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            data-placement="right"
            title="Ajouter une ligne"
            ><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i
          ></a>
        </span>
        <table id="example" class="table table-responsive-md text-center">
          <thead>
            <!-- TITLES OF COLUMNS -->
            <tr class="mescouilles">
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="false">Grade</th>
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">EFF THEO</th>
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">ABS</th>
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">PRESENT</th>
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">INDISPONIBLE</th>
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="true">SLR</th>
              <th class="text-center" contenteditable="false">SUPPRIMER</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!-- OFF ROW -->
            <tr class="cucul">
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="true">Off</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input id="value2" type="number" name="value2" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="1" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color: #b0bda2;" />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input id="value9" type="number" name="value9" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="2" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center colonneDeux" style="background-color: #b0bda2;" />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input id="value16" type="number" name="value16" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="3" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color: #b0bda2;" />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input id="value23" type="number" name="value23" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="4" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color: #b0bda2;" />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input id="value30" type="number" name="value30" value="0" placeholder="0" data-col="5" class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center" style="background-color: #b0bda2;" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="table-remove"><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                  >
                    SUPPRIMER
                  </button></span
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- S/OFF ROW -->
            <tr>
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">S/OFF</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value3"
                  type="number"
                  name="value3"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="1"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value10"
                  type="number"
                  name="value10"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="2"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center colonneDeux"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value17"
                  type="number"
                  name="value17"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="3"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value24"
                  type="number"
                  name="value24"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="4"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value31"
                  type="number"
                  name="value31"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="5"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="table-remove"
                  ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                  >
                    SUPPRIMER
                  </button></span
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- CCH ROW -->
            <tr>
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="flase">CCH</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value4"
                  type="number"
                  name="value4"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="1"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value11"
                  type="number"
                  name="value11"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="2"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value18"
                  type="number"
                  name="value18"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="3"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value25"
                  type="number"
                  name="value25"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="4"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value32"
                  type="number"
                  name="value32"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="5"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="table-remove"
                  ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                  >
                    SUPPRIMER
                  </button></span
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- CPL ROW -->
            <tr>
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">CPL</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value5"
                  type="number"
                  name="value5"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="1"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value12"
                  type="number"
                  name="value12"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="2"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value19"
                  type="number"
                  name="value19"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="3"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value26"
                  type="number"
                  name="value26"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="4"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value33"
                  type="number"
                  name="value33"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="5"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="table-remove"
                  ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                  >
                    SUPPRIMER
                  </button></span
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- ICL ROW -->
            <tr>
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">ICL</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value6"
                  type="number"
                  name="value6"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="1"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value13"
                  type="number"
                  name="value13"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="2"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value20"
                  type="number"
                  name="value20"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="3"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value27"
                  type="number"
                  name="value27"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="4"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value34"
                  type="number"
                  name="value34"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="5"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="table-remove"
                  ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
                  >
                    SUPPRIMER
                  </button></span
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- LEG ROW -->
            <tr>
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">LEG</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value7"
                  type="number"
                  name="value7"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="1"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value14"
                  type="number"
                  name="value14"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="2"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value21"
                  type="number"
                  name="value21"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="3"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value28"
                  type="number"
                  name="value28"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="4"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true">
                <input
                  id="value35"
                  type="number"
                  name="value35"
                  value="0"
                  placeholder="0"
                  data-col="5"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #b0bda2;"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span class="table-remove"
                  ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 shadow-none"
                  >
                    SUPPRIMER
                  </button></span
                >
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <!-- TOTAL OF COLUMNS -->
            <tr style="background-color: #c5d3b6; border-width: 3px;">
              <td class="pt-3-half colonne" contenteditable="false">TOTAL</td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                <input
                  disabled="disabled"
                  id="sum"
                  type="number"
                  name="sum"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="0"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #c5d3b6;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                <input
                  disabled="disabled"
                  id="sum2"
                  type="number"
                  name="sum2"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="0"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #c5d3b6;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                <input
                  disabled="disabled"
                  id="sum3"
                  type="number"
                  name="sum3"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="0"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #c5d3b6;"
                />
              </td>
              <td class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="false">
                <input
                  disabled="disabled"
                  id="sum4"
                  type="number"
                  name="sum4"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="0"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #c5d3b6;"
                />
              </td>
              <td contenteditable="false">
                <input
                  disabled="disabled"
                  id="sum5"
                  type="number"
                  name="sum5"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="0"
                  class="form-control form-control-sm border border-0 text-center"
                  style="background-color: #c5d3b6;"
                />
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Editable table -->

  <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's helpful @Vladlen Tereshchenko, now I'm gonna do the same for the values when I delete.